# Relocating product link in WooCommerce archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The link I am trying to relocate is the link that wraps each product on the shop page which takes you to that products own page. As it is right now it wraps the image, product name, product sku and price. I only want it to wrap the image and product name.

Here's the code which is creating each product.

```
<li <?php post_class( $boot_classes ); ?>>
    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
</li>
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the location of the product link close as you expect, this way:

```
add_action('init', 'change_location_of_loop_product_link_close' );
function change_location_of_loop_product_link_close(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
    add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 20 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.